# Ubuntu 14.04 Does Not Recognize Mac OS X During Installation

Tags: dual-boot, mac

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my Macbook Pro 6,2 (mid-2010) alongside Yosemite. Using this [handy guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/), I installed rEFInd and made a bootable USB drive. I had some problems starting the installer from the bootable USB, so I instead burned the .iso to a DVD.

When I put the DVD in, rEFInd recognizes that the DVD is a bootable drive, and I can boot off of it under the "Try Ubuntu" option. I then run the installer, but instead of giving me the option to "Install Alongside Mac OS X", it says that Ubuntu did not detect any other operating systems, and gives the me the options to erase my disk, or do the process manually ("Something else"). A previous user who had this problem suggested using the computer's built-in boot option, so I started it by pressing alt upon startup, and had two disk icons: Windows and EFI Boot. EFI boot didn't get me anywhere, but Windows got me to the same Try Ubuntu screen, but with the same problem.

Also, I've got a 1 TB hard drive with 900 GB partitioned to HFS+ for Yosemite, leaving about 100 GB of "Free Space."